# Is it possible to change position of textField using JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created *.jrxml* by using iReport tool and have to dynamically set the x and y position of fields in *.jrxml* file. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid thats not directly possible using reports made in iReport, creating the reports in runtime in Java will solve your issue.