# Is it possible to have a variable as value in Jasper XML

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make a table with dynamic headers for a PDF in Grails using Jasper. One of the possible solutions would be to have a property as a value for an xml attribute. I have a hard time explaining it in English,so maybe it's better to leave an example, here is the xml code for a static header in a table:

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="29" y="183" width="118" height="32"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
        <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[Column header text]]></text>
</staticText>
```

What I want to know is, is it possible to have a parameter for the value of x, y and every other attribute value for the element, like for an example this:

```
<staticText>
     <reportElement x="<![CDATA[$P{columnX}]]>" y="<![CDATA[$P{columnY}]]>" width="<![CDATA[$P{columnWidth}]]>" height=32/>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
        <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[Column header text]]></text>
</staticText>
```

The parameter would be declared like this:

```
 <parameter name="columnX" class="java.lang.Long"/>
```

Comment: The answer is: No. You can use *JasperReports API* or another Java API

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Problem with Jasper Report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1797356/876298)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help, it's a shame that it isn't possible! I will start making myself familiar with the JasperReports API..

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: You can look at [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org) & [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com)